# How should I convert merge used in pipe in v5 to v6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm looking at the convert guide available [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) and I'm trying to convert merge used in pipe following this guide, but it is not working as it was before the change.

Here is my piece of code I'm using to learn new merge:

```js
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(1),
      merge(this.form.statusChanges),
      merge(this.click$),
      map(() => this.form.value.query),
      filter(() => this.form.valid)
    )
    .subscribe(this.search);
```

```js
  private search = (query: string) => {
    this.tvs.search(query).subscribe(shows => this.shows = shows);
  }
```

I've tried to do something like that:

```js
    merge(
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(1),
      map(() => this.form.value.query),
      debounceTime(500),
      tap(() => this.form.controls.query.errors && console.log(this.form.controls.query.errors)),
      tap(() => this.form.status && console.log(this.form.status)),
      filter(() => this.form.valid)
    ), this.form.statusChanges, this.click$)
    .subscribe(this.search);
```

But in network tab in chrome I'm getting the call to api with query equal to status of the form (VALID or INVALID). What is the proper way to convert this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this:

```js
 merge(
      this.form.valueChanges,
      this.form.statusChanges,
      this.click$).pipe(
        startWith(1),
        map(() => this.form.value.query),
        debounceTime(500),
        tap(() => this.form.controls.query.errors && console.log(this.form.controls.query.errors)),
        tap(() => this.form.status && console.log(this.form.status)),
        filter(() => this.form.valid)
      ).subscribe(this.search);
```